# Generating an html table of pages visited by users ordered by user and then by the last page visited from MySQL table

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

I have a MySQL table that logs logged in users visits to each of the pages on a website.  It has a column for users, one for the name of the page visited, and one for the time/date that it was visited.

I would like to generate a table using a MySQL query to summarise the information from this table in the format below, i.e. I would like the table to be sorted primarily by the date the user last visited, but then a row for each page they have visited (one row for each page visited (I have used three pages to illustrate but really I would like all pages listed), even if they have visited the page multiple times), sorted by the time/date of the last visit to this page, and with a column for the total number of visits the user has made to the page:

[image]

I have tried various queries using GROUP by and DISTINCT but I'm not getting very close, so would be glad of some help to get this working.

Comment: do you want only the `top 3` pages whom the user has visited?

Comment: @JohnWoo No, I just used 3 pages to illustrate. I'd like all of the pages a user has listed visited, and also with a count of the number of times they have visited each page (I will add this info to the question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may well be a better way, but I solved this in the end using two queries.  The first returns a unique row for each name:

```
SELECT *,COUNT(DISTINCT Page) AS count_page FROM visits GROUP by Name ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC";
```

I then used count_page to set a rowspan for each cell with a Name in:

```
echo "<tr><td ROWSPAN=\"".$row['count_page']."\">";
```

And then, within the loop for each Name I ran a second query which returned a row for each unique page per Name:

```
"SELECT Page, unix_timestamp(NOW()) - unix_timestamp(MAX(Date)) as time_page, COUNT(Page) as Count FROM visits WHERE Name='".$row['Name']."' GROUP by Page ORDER BY MAX(Date) DESC"
```

I could then use `$row['Page']`, `$row['time_page']` and `$row['Count']` to return the additional information I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You might need to tweak this as I couldn't completely replicate your scenario

```
Select * from
(
select 

    page, 
    visitdate
    userid,
    @rank:=case when @tmpuserid<>userid then 1
    else
      IFNULL(@rank,0)+1 
    end as rank,
    @tmpuserid:=userid as tmpuserid

from pages
order by visitdate
) p
Where  p.rank <=3
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like you are setting the query to just return the top three pages?  Is this so?  If so, I presume I just drop `Where  p.rank <=3` to return all the pages. Correct?  Also, I am not sure how to construct the html table to work with you query.  Clearly it is not as straight forward as just using `while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){` and then echoing the rows.  Could you help with this?

Comment: did you try it. It should return the top 3 for each user

Comment: Yes, I tried it, substituting the actual names of the columns in my table and it returned all rows from the table, i.e. nearly 5000, and in no particular order

Comment: Thanks. It is hard for me to make sense of the table that is generated on the fiddle.  I am seeing a date under UserID and I am not seeing any pages grouped by user.

Comment: That's why I said you will need to tweak the query. I have updated the fiddle, hope that works. But you still have to fine-tune

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I couldn't get my somewhat dim head round your method.  I've now got what I was looking for using the solution below.